# Why can't I automatically create definition files in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am making my first steps in C++ and after creating a class header file I want to automatically create a definition file by pressing Ctrl+., but Visual Studio tells me that it couldn't create one. I always have to manually create one and then it works. Also, when I put the headers and source files in separate folders, Visual Studio tells me that the file is write protected. All files are located in my profile folder, so there should be no write protection.

Any ideas why this could be?

Comment: So you right click somewhere on your project `Add -> New Item -> Module definition file` doesn't work?

Comment: No, that works. I want to auto-create constructors etc. via ``Ctrl+.`` and this only works if there has been a .cpp file created manually before

Comment: You create source C++ files. They may or not contain definitions and declarations. A file with only a comment is legal. See [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf). What matters are *translation units*, see [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp). Also, some C++ files could be generated (e.g. by [ANTLR](https://antlr.org/) or some other programs). Don't forget to read the documentation of your C++ compiler and debugger

Comment: You could use [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) to create C++ files, and [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) to compile them. Enable all warnings and debug info, so with GCC use `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`. Be aware of the [C++ rule of five](https://cpppatterns.com/patterns/rule-of-five.html).

Comment: I know I could use emacs, vim or gcc, but I was asking about Visual Studio

Comment: Are you allowed to study the C++ source code of existing open source projects? Are you allowed to use the [Clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/)? It could be helpful

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you could refer to the Doc: [Create Declaration / Definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/ide/refactoring/create-declaration-definition?view=msvc-160)

> When: You have a function that needs a declaration, or vice-versa.

As far as I'm concerned, first of all, you should have a function that needs a declaration.

Comment: Well thank you, but this is exactly what doesn’t work.